# kivy: overriding __init__ makes child layouts display too small

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently working on a kivy project and have discovered a strange issue. If I override the __init__ method for the root layout, its children display much smaller than they should. Why does this happen, and what's the correct way to override __init__? Here's a minimized example:

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:set camera_width_percent 4.0/5.0
#:set sidebar_width (1.0 - camera_width_percent) / 2.0

<LeftSidebar>:
    ok_btn_button: ok_btn
    #:set num_btns 10.0
    size_hint: (sidebar_width, 1.0)

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    CustomButton:
        id: ok_btn
        text: "ok"
        size_hint: (1.0, 1.0/num_btns)
        pos_hint: {'top': 1.0/num_btns}


<LifterGUI>:
    left_sidebar_widget: left_sidebar

    FloatLayout:
        LeftSidebar:
            id: left_sidebar
```

### test.py, WITHOUT **init** override of LifterGUI

[Here's the GUI's appearance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUAC4.png)

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.fullscreen = 'auto'

class CustomButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("CustomButton __init__ called")


class LeftSidebar(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LeftSidebar __init__ called")


class LifterGUI(FloatLayout):

#    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
#        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
#        print("LifterGUI __init__ called")
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        lifterGUI = LifterGUI()
        return lifterGUI


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.py, WITH **init** override of LifterGUI

[And here's what it looks like after the change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7NYu.png)

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.fullscreen = 'auto'

class CustomButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("CustomButton __init__ called")


class LeftSidebar(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LeftSidebar __init__ called")


class LifterGUI(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LifterGUI __init__ called")
#    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        lifterGUI = LifterGUI()
        return lifterGUI


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `super`, you should provide the class that you are calling from. For example:

```
class LifterGUI(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LifterGUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LifterGUI __init__ called")
```

Similar for your other classes.